# I have a graph execution error in python. How can I solve this?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to create a graph for the outputs:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import wrapt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical 
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

# read data
data=pd.read_csv('adult-stretch.data', header=None)

# convert to arrays
x=data.iloc[:, :4].to_numpy()
t=data[4].replace(['T','F'],[0,1])
t=t.to_numpy()


# split the dataset
xTrain, xTest, tTrain, tTest = train_test_split(x, t, test_size=0.2, random_state=3)

# convert to categorical (hot encoding)
tTrainHot = to_categorical(tTrain)
tTestHot = to_categorical(tTest)

# create network
net=models.Sequential()
#net.add(layers.Dense(5,activation="relu", input_shape=(4,)))
net.add(layers.Dense(5,activation="relu", input_shape=(np.size(x,1),)))
#net.add(layers.Dense(3,activation="sigmoid"))
net.add(layers.Dense(np.size(tTrainHot, 1),activation="sigmoid"))
print(net.summary())    #see the network structure


# set network train parameters
net.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics='accuracy')

#train the network
history = net.fit(xTrain, tTrainHot, epochs=300, validation_split=0.2)

     
plt.close('all')
plt.plot(history.history['loss'],label='Training Loss',linewidth=3)
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'],label='Validation Loss',linewidth=3)
plt.legend()
plt.grid('on')
plt.title('Loss')
 
plt.figure()
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'],label='Training Accuracy',linewidth=3)
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'],label='Validation Accuracy',linewidth=3)
plt.legend()
plt.grid('on')
plt.title('Accuracy')


lossTest, accTest = net.evaluate(xTest, tTestHot)
print('accTest=', accTest)

# real output (hot-encoded)
yTestHot = net.predict(xTest)

# convert yTest to label vector
yTest = np.argmax(yTestHot, axis=1)
print(confusion_matrix(tTest, yTest))
```

and i just keep getting this graph execution error:

```
Detected at node 'sequential_23/Cast' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder_kernels/console/__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
      start.main()
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder_kernels/console/start.py", line 328, in main
      kernel.start()
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 677, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 199, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 596, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1890, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 457, in dispatch_queue
      await self.process_one()
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 446, in process_one
      await dispatch(*args)
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 353, in dispatch_shell
      await result
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 648, in execute_request
      reply_content = await reply_content
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 353, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2901, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2947, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 68, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3172, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3364, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3444, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "/var/folders/v6/jqcvfqns1gn7zy2m3pcvzrqm0000gn/T/ipykernel_702/4012300658.py", line 1, in <module>
      runfile('/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/Downloads/Lab/Lab3/nnga3_ex1.py', wdir='/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/Downloads/Lab/Lab3')
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 577, in runfile
      exec_code(file_code, filename, ns_globals, ns_locals,
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 465, in exec_code
      exec(compiled, ns_globals, ns_locals)
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/Downloads/Lab/Lab3/nnga3_ex1.py", line 40, in <module>
      history = net.fit(xTrain, tTrainHot, epochs=300, validation_split=0.2)
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1384, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 859, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1096, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 374, in call
      return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 451, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 571, in _run_internal_graph
      y = self._conform_to_reference_input(y, ref_input=x)
    File "/Users/ispasdinu-ioan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 671, in _conform_to_reference_input
      tensor = tf.cast(tensor, dtype=ref_input.dtype)
Node: 'sequential_23/Cast'
Cast string to float is not supported
     [[{{node sequential_23/Cast}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_10601]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ML models train on numerics, you are passing input of type object to the neural network. Changing the input to numerics will help. You can use pd.get_dummies() to one-hot encode the categorical features as follows:

```
data1=pd.get_dummies(data[0])
data2=pd.get_dummies(data[1])
data3=pd.get_dummies(data[2])
data4=pd.get_dummies(data[3])

#you can concatenate the one-hot encoded values by using pd.concat
data = pd.concat([data1,data2,data3,data4,data[4]], axis='columns')
```

After one-hot encoding the dataset looks like this

[image]

Please find the working code [here](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/kiransairamineni/dc69cb25e4867832df7f6aacff897318/so_72129543.ipynb). Thank you.